# Match two columns in MongoDB

Tags: python, sql, mongodb, pymongo, aggregate-functions

I have two columns `state` and `date` and I wanted to match it by passing dynamic values in python and below is the query I used, but it is not returning any values

[image]

Kindly let me know the MongoDB query for the below SQL query:

```
select sum(cases) from COVID19_DB.COVID19.NYTIMES_US_STATES where state='Wyoming' and date='2020-05-23' order by date asc;
```

Thanks,
Sumesh.

Comment: Please, paste the code as text, provide an example of your document and the expected output.

Comment: I just wanted the MongoDB query for the above SQL query. you can consider two documents with state ='Wyoming', date =' 2020-05-23' ,cases = 23 and second document with state ='Wyoming' ,date='2020-03-23',cases =23 and expected output for the above query must be 23 from the documents when matching state and date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading your comment I understand that you only need a simple `find` query matching two values.

I think you want to say "field" when you say "column", so you only have to match both values like this:

```js
db.collection.find({
  "state": "Wyoming",
  "date": "2020-05-23"
})
```

Check this [example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0jhohSuky7a).

But, if you are using an aggregation, then you can using `$match` in [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EilOqCYJaAQ) way

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "state": "Wyoming",
      "date": "2020-05-23"
    }
  }
])
```

As you can see, match multiple "columns" is only find by all values you want.